# Angular 2 RC5 => RC6 migration causes Injector problems

Tags: angular, typescript

I had an Angular2 RC5 application that was working perfectly, after upgrading to RC6 my application stops working with message:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (?, ?).

I have fairly typical Angular2 setup, here is the code for `LoginComponent`, every injected parameter in constructor has `@Injectable()` annotation

```
import {AuthService} from "../../auth/auth-service";

import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-component',
  templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['login/login.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private model = {login: '', password: ''};

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }


    protected doLogin(event: Event) {
        this.authService.login(this.model.login, this.model.password).then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is app-module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {AppService} from './app-service'
import {AuthService} from "./auth/auth-service";
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./component/app-component";
import {ChessComponent} from './component/chess/chess-component';
import {LoginComponent} from "./component/login/login-component";
import {LandingComponent} from "./component/landing/landing-component";
import {AuthGuardService} from "./auth/auth-guard-service";
import {GuidService} from "./shared/guid-service";
import {EchoService} from "./io/echo-service";
import {PermissionsService} from "./permissions-service";
import {
    EnumerateSetValuesPipe, EnumerateMapPipe, EnumerateMapKeysPipe, EnumerateMapValuesPipe,
    EnumerateObjectPipe, EnumerateObjectKeysPipe, EnumerateObjectValuesPipe,
    NeighbouringValuesPipe
} from "./shared/pipes";

import { TinyComponent } from "./component/tiny/tiny";
import {HtmlService} from "./component/docs/html-service";
import {DocsComponent} from "./component/docs/docs-component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([{
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/landing',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }, {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
        }, {
            path: 'docs',
            component: DocsComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
        }, {
            path: 'chess',
            component: ChessComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
        }, {
            path: 'landing',
            component: LandingComponent,
        }])
    ],
    providers: [
        AppService,
        AuthService,
        GuidService,
        EchoService,
        HtmlService,
        AuthGuardService,
        PermissionsService
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TinyComponent,
        ChessComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        LandingComponent,

        EnumerateSetValuesPipe,
        EnumerateMapPipe,
        EnumerateMapKeysPipe,
        EnumerateMapValuesPipe,
        EnumerateObjectPipe,
        EnumerateObjectKeysPipe,
        EnumerateObjectValuesPipe,
        NeighbouringValuesPipe
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    public constructor() {

    }
}
```

Not sure how to debug such problem... Any thoughts?

Comment: How does the `@NgModule()` look like?

Comment: added it, btw my IDE is barking on HttpModule saying that it can't resolve the symbol???

Comment: Can't find anything suspicious.

Comment: make sure you have updated you npm modules by `npm install` inside your project directive after updating package.json. Try `npm install` after removing `node_modules` directive for your project directive.

Comment: Didn't help, I've debugged angular, and found out if you provide parameter annotations explicitly on constructor parameters it works fine...

Comment: @Lu4, did you mean `@Inject` decorator?

Comment: Had bunch of similar issues going RC5->RC6. They were all gone after I referenced everything correctly. Please note that in RC6 if you are using SystemJS, you should adjust your SystemJS configuration to point to the UMD bundles. Example config: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/systemjs.config.js#L17-L34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the way @Injector was declared, not sure how it worked previously but I had it declared this way `@Injectable` instead of `@Injectable()`.

When you decorate your class with `@Injectable` call it misunderstands the decorator.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem for one of my components. In another app which uses the same component, there is no such error. So it must have something to do with the way it's declared or applied via modules.

And strangely enough, you get the same error if the source for your component is not loaded (wrong path to file).